# Expected time of coming back to origin when one move randomly on a line.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to calculate the expected time of coming back to origin when one move randomly on a line.

＊At $t=0$, a man is at the origin.
＊From $t=n$ to $n+1$, the man move from $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$.
＊$|x_n-x_{n+1}|=1$
＊At each integer second, the man flip a coin. Depending on the face of coin front or back, he move left or right. The probability of front and back is same.
＊The man will sleep when he come back to the origin.

Can we calculate the expected time of the man to coming back to the origin?

Let $a_n:=$ the expected time of the man coming to the position of $n$.

Then, $a_n=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+1)+\frac{1}{2}(a_{n+1}+1)=1+\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+a_{n+1})$ except $n=0$.

If $n=0,$ $a_0=\frac{1}{2}(a_{1}+1)$. Can we calculate $a_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the walk will return infinitely often, the expected time of coming back to the origin when one moves randomly in a line is infinity, since there is an equal probability of moving to the "left" and to the "right" each step (simple random walk). http://www2.math.uu.se/~sea/kurser/stokprocmn1/slumpvandring_eng.pdf (page 6) 
[Random Walk, Recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602441/random-walk-recurrence-relation)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i$.

From $a_n=1+\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+a_{n+1})$ except $n=0$,

$$
\begin{align}
&(x^2-2x+1)f(x)=a_0-2\sum_{i=1}^\infty x\\
\Leftrightarrow &f(x)=\frac{a_0}{(1-x)^2}-2\frac{x}{(1-x)^3} \\
\Leftrightarrow &f(x)=a_0\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^k-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{2}x^{k+1}\\
\end{align}
$$

In order to satisfy $a_0=\frac{1}{2}(a_{1}+1)$,
$$a_0=\frac{1}{2}(2a_0-1)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 0=-\frac{1}{2}$$

This is contradiction. Thus the $a_0$ is not finite number.